# Documentation for Python binding for MLT multimedia framework

Tags: python, multimedia, mlt

I am start learning [MLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Lovin%27_Toolkit) multimedia framework. It's written in C/C++ so its official [documentation](http://www.mltframework.org/bin/view/MLT/Documentation) has tutorials and examples for C/C++ only with few links for Perl binding.

I am looking for some tutorials for Python bindings of MLT, because I want to use MLT with Python. I tried a lot on google but could not find any single documentation page.

basically I have to join few images and videos to make a single video and I have to add audio too in final video. I have to do all this in bulk for lot of videos so I am writing a script in Python. till than I am running MLT's `melt` command line utility s subprocess of my script. but that command is not very programmable.

Answer (score 6):

There are a bunch of example python scripts on the [MLT Code Examples Page](https://github.com/mltframework/mlt/tree/master/src/swig/python). They're fairly simple but should provide a starting point.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, you need to learn the C API and extrapolate it to Python. It is easier than it sounds because the C API is object-based and uses reference-counting. The key is to understand that the Python (and other high level language bindings) are generated using SWIG using the mlt++ C++ wrapper. If you compare the C++ header files to the C header files, you can see a fairly direct mapping from one to the other because the C++ API is simply a thin wrapper. Then, compare the mlt Python calls from the examples to the C++ headers to learn how the C++ names convert to Python. Lastly, you can study the code of Flowblade and OpenShot 1.x code to figure out more.